# TypeScript: return a union of the input string array's literal values?

Tags: typescript, generics

Can I type a function such that it takes a `string[]` and the output is a string union?

For example, given this function:

```
function myfn(strs: string[]) {
  return strs[0];
}
```

If I call it like:

```
myfn(['a', 'b', 'c']) // => return type is: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add generic parameter to describe the array item, typescript will be able to infer it from provided value:

```
function myfn<T extends string>(strs: T[]) {
  return strs[0];
}

const result = myfn(['a', 'b', 'c']) // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ7DAHgCqIKYAeUeYAJgM6LlQBOMYA5gHwAU1N5AXItgNoC6ASkQBvALAAoRIhp4oIGknbleABn4BuSQF9JkiAmoy85EABsoiALwp0YFrwDkAQ0cAaRI4BG7zxEdCiAD0QYgARM5hiAA%204V5RsWEQYUA)