# TypeScript: map object types containing string unions into return result

Tags: typescript, generics

This is an extension of this question: [TypeScript: return a union of the input string array's literal values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283229/typescript-return-a-union-of-the-input-string-arrays-literal-values#67283558)

This question extends that last question by embedding the literal-tuple into arbitrary keys on an object, and maps them on the output keys.

```
function myfn<T extends string>(opts: { [key: string]: T[] }) {
  const out: ??? = {};
  for (const [key,val] of Object.entries(opts)) {
    out[key] = val[0];
  }
  return out;
}

const result = myfn({
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  bar: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
})

// Expected: {
//   foo: 'a' | 'b' | 'c',
//   bar: 'x' | 'y' | 'z',
// }
```

What types need to be in/on `myfn` to get the expected types?

I know this has to do with [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), but I can't figure out exactly what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have a full answer right now, but this was the type you were looking for:

```
type MapToUnion<T extends { [key: string]: readonly string[] }> =
    {
        -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K][number]
    }

const opts = {
    foo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    bar: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
} as const;

type Mapped = MapToUnion<typeof opts>;

// type Mapped = {
//     foo: "a" | "b" | "c";
//     bar: "x" | "y" | "z";
// }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `as const`?

Comment: @Steven not the answerer, if you don't do a `const` assertion and you let the compiler infer the type of `opts`, it will choose the not-unreasonable `{foo: string[], bar: string[]}`, which completely forgets about any possible string literals.  `const` assertions are by far the easiest way for you to tell the compiler to remember those string literals.

Comment: This can be done, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283229/typescript-return-a-union-of-the-input-string-arrays-literal-values#67283558 -- what I'm trying to do here is combine that with Type Mapping, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

User `systemfault` on `Freenode` in `##typescript` wrote this solution:

```
type MyFnResult<T extends string, Options extends {readonly [k:string]: T[]}> = Options extends any? { [K in keyof Options]: Options[K][number] } : never

function myfn<
  T extends string,
  Options extends {readonly [k:string]: T[] }
>(opts: Options): MyFnResult<T, Options> {
  const out: Record<string, string> = {};

  for (const [key,val] of Object.entries(opts)) {
    out[key] = val[0];
  }
  return out as any
}

const result = myfn({
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  bar: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
})

// Out type: {
//   foo: 'a' | 'b' | 'c',
//   bar: 'x' | 'y' | 'z',
// }
```

It works. I don't understand it one bit. But it works.

Comment: That's the same as my answer tho, I just didn't want the `as any` cast for the full answer. Types `MyFnResult` and `MapToUnion` are functionally the same.

Comment: His doesn't use `as const` which I think is the main difference, but an important one.